# How to declare variables in C unions?

Tags: c, unions

I just started with C and I am reading head first C. According to that book's I defined a union and try to declare variables in it. But it doesn't give the expected output.Here is the code

```C
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union{
    short count;
    float weight;
    float volume;
} quantity;

int main()
{
    quantity q;
    q.count = 4;
    q.weight = 1.7;
    q.volume = 3.7;
    
    printf("count = %i\tweight = %.2f\tvolume = %2.f\t", q.count, q.weight, q.volume);
}
```

Here is the output

```
count = -13107    weight = 3.70    volume = 3.70
```

Why am I getting a negative number for count and same floating-point for weight and volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have missed the section in your text book that said that all members of a union *share* the exact same memory, and that the value of all member will be the value of the *memory bit pattern* used in the last assignment to a member.

Since you set the `volume` member last, then all member will have the same in-memory bit pattern as the `float` value `3.7`.

And integers and floating point values have different bit patterns in memory, so the value for `count` will seem almost random or garbage.

If you want three distinct and separate members you need a *structure* and not a union.

Comment: Is that means that because union shares one memory location, we can't use this union

Comment: @AeshaAmoli: You can use each union _for one variable at a time_. Use a `struct` to store multiple.

Answer (score 2):

A [`union`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) allows to store different data types in the same memory location. You can define a union with many members, but only one member can contain a value at any given time. That is why only the last element you initialized is printed correctly. What you might be looking for is a [`struct`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm).

```
typedef struct {
    short count;
    float weight;
    float volume;
} quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `union` has shared memory for each of its members, so it can only store one of them at a time.  If you write to one member and read another one, you'll get something else out.

If you want to be able to hold all of these values at once, you want a `struct`.

```
typedef struct {
    short count;
    float weight;
    float volume;
} quantity;
```

Comment: yeah... i know but i'm gonna use this union inside a struct. And this is just a test if it is works...

Answer (score 0):

A union is a special data type available in C that allows to store different data types in the same memory location. You can define a union with many members, but only one member can contain a value at any given time.

so if you want to store value in all three variables then you should use struct.

```
typedef struct {
     short count;
     float weight;
     float volume;
}
```